# ERROR : BOMStream BOMStreamWithFileAndSys(int, off_t, size_t, int, char *, BomSys *): read: No such file or directory in iOS

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, nsurl

I am downloading a mp4 file from my server. Yesterday it was fine.

Now I am getting this **Error** :

```
  BOMStream BOMStreamWithFileAndSys(int, off_t, size_t, int, char *, BomSys *): read: No such file or directory
```

And my download suddenly finished and progress showing : -80%

below is my Output :

```
2016-04-28 11:07:43.816 NSURLSample[10581:112570] BOMStream BOMStreamWithFileAndSys(int, off_t, size_t, int, char *, BomSys *): read: No such file or directory
2016-04-28 11:07:43.816 NSURLSample[10581:112570] Done.......
2016-04-28 11:07:43.817 NSURLSample[10581:112570] progress == -80.000000
```

How can I avoid this error. Please suggest me.

Comment: Are you downloading the file to the Documents directory?

Comment: Same problem with me ... when downloading mp4 into document directory

Comment: It was some server side issue. Now its working fine.....:)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when i try to download an image from documents directory by a NSstring path. checking null or invalid path solved these for me. 
Like i was try to fetch an image by path. and the path is nil. Then i set a checking and then pass it.
Try it.